# Spring Roo JDialog Form update table contents

Tags: jquery, jstl, spring-roo

I have this `JQuery` dialog containing a `<input>` and `<table>`. The `<input>` is a filter field for the *onload* contents of `<table>`. I've heard `JQGrid` has this feature but this module isn't an option for me for now.

I tried searching about other solution(s) and come up with `AJAX`. I am using `Spring-Roo` for this thread and since `AJAX` can be a solution I am new to this `AJAX` thing. Here's the structure of the code of the view without any `javascript`.

```
<form:form action="POST" action="form_action" modelAttribute="form">
    <div>
        <form:input path="filterField" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />          
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <c:forEach items="${items}" var="itr">
                <tr>
                    <td>${itr.data}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

I am new to `JQuery`, `AJAX`, and `Spring-Roo`. A detailed instruction on this can be done is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a very general request, I will try to give you a very general answer.

You will need several things to make an Asynchronous call, and you will need to make several decisions.  Understand that AJAX doesn't really mean AJAX anymore, but is a general term now applied to any process by which you make an asynchronous call from a browser-based client to some sort of back-end.

First, you will need to write a method to handle your AJAX request.  This is the first decision you must make: What are the request parameters to your service and what is the resulting payload.  I am preferential to the RESTful JSON type requests, but a lot of people like XML.  For a RESTful JSON version, you can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/widgets/{id}")
public @ResponseBody Widget getMyWidget(@PathVariable Integer id) {
  // ...perform some lookup, idealy in a service layer
  Widget myWidget = myService.findWidget(id);
  return myWidget;
}
```

The important parts here are the `@ResponseBody` and the `return myWidget`.  In Spring, `@ResponseBody` indicates that the return will be literally copied into the response body.  So, for instance, you could return a String that has HTML code, and it is merely copy/pasted into the response.  This is opposite of the normal return, which is usually some String name that represents a `View`.  The second bit of PFM (pure friggen magic) is the return of type Wiget.  As long as you have the Jackson library in your path, Spring will auto-magically use it to serialize your return to JSON.  This takes care of the server side.

On the client-side, you need to call your service on the server.  First, ditch the `<input type="submit" value="Search" />`, and make it a type button instead.  Using a submit type will only cause you issues as it will attempt to submit the form, which is NOT asynchronous.  Attach a jQuery click handler to the button, and use it's [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to call your service.  Again, there are LOTS of options, and there is no way I will go through them all.  But, the general idea here is to do something like this:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://myhost/myController/widget/1',
    success: function(data) {
      // Do something with the widget, like fill a table full of stuff
    }
  });
});
```

The $.ajax() call in jQuery has a ton of options, and there are examples all over the place.  You will probably also want to handle error responses too...this example only shows handling the success.

That should at least get you started.  You will have to investigate all the options and possibilities on your own, as I can't make architectural decisions for your as I don't know your application nor the circumstances involved.

Comment: I see. So if I am going to display the data (which is `java.util.List<E>`) on a particular table, I would code the html layout inside the script?

Comment: If you want a dynamic list, populated by an AJAX call to the backend, you would have some wrapper/place-holder in the default HTML, then use the AJAX returned values to build the list dynamically.  Since it looks like you are building a table, I would say what you want to do is empty all the table rows (remove them totally), then loop through the values returned, appending a new row and column to the table for each value.  This is fairly common practice, and jQuery makes most of that pretty easy.